# C++ library built for Android uses wrong dependency symbols

Tags: android, c++

When I build my C++ library using standalone toolchain, it compiles successfully but fails at runtime with undefined symbols for the dependent library:

```
06-03 15:16:29.554  3599  3619 D Unity   : Unable to load library '/data/app/com.x.y.z.app-_VFxANKGcCeB5wdqbLmvgQ==/lib/arm/libmylib.so', native render plugin support disabled: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN3ndn18MemoryContentCache4Impl26getPendingInterestsForNameERKNS_4NameERSt6vectorISt10shared_ptrIKNS0_15PendingInterestEESaIS9_EE" referenced by "/data/app/com.ux.y.z.app
```

Unmangled symbol is `ndn::MemoryContentCache::Impl::getPendingInterestsForName(ndn::Name const&, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ndn::MemoryContentCache::PendingInterest const>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<ndn::MemoryContentCache::PendingInterest const> > >&)`.

This symbol is indeed missing in the dependent library, instead, this one is present: `_ZN3ndn18MemoryContentCache4Impl26getPendingInterestsForNameERKNS_4NameERNSt6__ndk16vectorINS5_10shared_ptrIKNS0_15PendingInterestEEENS5_9allocatorISA_EEEE` which is `ndn::MemoryContentCache::Impl::getPendingInterestsForName(ndn::Name const&, std::__ndk1::vector<std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<ndn::MemoryContentCache::PendingInterest const>, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<ndn::MemoryContentCache::PendingInterest const> > >&)`.

As can be seen, the dependent library uses `std::__ndk1::vector` class whereas my library compiles with just `std::vector`.

Hence, questions:

1) What is `__ndk1` prefix? I believe it is NDK's std library implementation, but better understanding is needed.

2) Why my library doesn't use it? I tried passing `-static-libstdc++` to `LDFLAGS` or `-DANDROID_STL=c++_static` and `-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared` with no luck. How can I force my library to use correct symbols?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this between Ubuntu 14 and 16. The cause is the version of GCC and the runtime ABI. [This GCC documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) explains how to use the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro to control what the linker looks for.

Comment: thanks! in my case i re-generated a toolchain with `--stl libc++` flag and it helped. apparently, by default, it uses `gnustl`?